# how to open prefab brush window in unity 2017.1.1f1?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a complete beginner in unity 3d and I rely on youtube and other sources to learn unity. I will get to the point.. I am currently watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXM1EQGO28c) @19:35 he opened a window called Prefab Brush but it is not available in mine which is Unity 2017.1.1f1. I believe in the future I might need this prefab brush, so I would like to ask some help.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjTwf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefab Brush is a plugin from the [Assetstore](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21321). It's was free at the time that video was made but the publisher decided to make it not free anymore. It cost only $2.99.

If you don't way to pay for that then use GeoPainter which is free and very similar to Prefab Brush. You can get GeoPainter [here](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/2389).